# Why does one of the faces show dotted in editmode?

Tags: modeling

I just started blender a few days ago and I noticed that when making faces, they sometimes have this dotted texture compared to the generic smooth texture. I have been having difficulties with this and was wondering why these dotted faces are different from the regular faces, how do I get rid of them and what are the advantages of using them?

This is my image:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It's possible it is a display bug in 2.67. If you want to experiment, you can try downloading the [newest version of Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/) which is 2.70, or maybe 2.69.

Comment: Its not a bug, recent versions of Blender only show when selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last selected faces is known as the **Active Face** and draws with a **Stipple** overlay (dots),

This is used to determine which texture to show in the image window, since its possible to UV map multiple images from a single mesh.

Comment: But the face is not selected -- several vertices are selected, and one is active. Wouldn't that make the stippled face neither active nor selected, and hence not stippled?

Comment: Actually, notice how none of the selected vertices seem to be connected to the surrounding edges? The active vertex (the white one) doesn't show highlighting outward, and neither does the one directly below the blue Z arrow. This suggests to me there may be lots of duplicate vertices and perhaps overlapping faces. And, maybe in 2.67 (which is what OP is using) these would have stippling-like effects, particularly if the normals are conflicting.

Comment: This behavior changed, now only selected+active faces show with stipple. (2.69+)

Comment: So, are you saying that in 2.67, the stippling shown here was supposed to be there & isn't a bug?

Comment: Right, in 2.70 its there too, just not displayed when the face isnt selected.