# Material is not displayed correctly on one face

Tags: modeling, materials

I have made a small eclipse type object with black material. One of the face is not displayed correctly in edit mode. It is displayed correctly in object mode and in final render. I have attached a screenshot with the culprit face highlighted in red circle.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the faces normals are flipped? What happens if you select everything in edit mode (A) and then press Ctrl+N?

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8314/why-does-one-of-the-faces-show-dotted-in-editmode/8315#8315

Comment: Thanks @cegaton. Please post this in answer section, I will mark it as answer.