# What are the faces with dotted patterns on them that seemingly cannot be subdivided

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

Ran into this a couple times while modelling this spaceship. A face will have dots all over it and when i try to subdivide it doesn't work. I do notice that the faces around it kind of wiggle around a little though?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dots mean the face is *Active*. See [Why does one of the faces show dotted in editmode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8314/599)

The reason why it apparently can't be subdivided is not due to it's selection state, but rather because it is an [*n-gon*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89/599). An n-gon is a faces made up of more than four edges.

Subdividing an n-gon won't create edges running through it, but will still add vertices to it's existing edges:

[image]

While in *Face Select* mode these verts won't be visible. To see them, switch to *Vertex Select* mode
(<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>).

Depending on what you are doing, n-gons should generally be avoided. See [When should N-Gons be used, and when shouldn't they?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89/599) for some more info.